# Why did not my custom Receiver get the right output?

Tags: spark-streaming

I have a question about custom receiver of spark streaming.
I code a copy like the following :

```
import java.io.{BufferedReader, InputStreamReader}
import java.net.Socket
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.Logging
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.receiver.Receiver

/**
  * Custom Receiver that receives data over a socket. Received bytes is interpreted as
  * text and \n delimited lines are considered as records. They are then counted and printed.
  *
  * To run this on your local machine, you need to first run a Netcat server
  *    `$ nc -lk 9999`
  * and then run the example
  *    `$ bin/run-example org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.CustomReceiver localhost 9999`
  */
object CustomReceiver2 {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {    

    // Create the context with a 1 second batch size
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("CustomReceiver")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(1))

    // Create a input stream with the custom receiver on target ip:port and count the
    // words in input stream of \n delimited text (eg. generated by 'nc')
    val lines = ssc.receiverStream(new CustomReceiver2("192.168.1.0", 11.toInt))

   lines.saveAsObjectFiles("hdfs:/tmp/customreceiver/")

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}


class CustomReceiver2(host: String, port: Int)
  extends Receiver[String](StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_2) with Logging {

  def onStart() {
    // Start the thread that receives data over a connection
    new Thread("Socket Receiver") {
      override def run() { receive() }
    }.start()
  }

  def onStop() {

  }

  /** Create a socket connection and receive data until receiver is stopped */
  private def receive() {
    var socket: Socket = null
    var userInput: String = null
    try {
      logInfo("Connecting to " + host + ":" + port)
      socket = new Socket(host, port)
      logInfo("Connected to " + host + ":" + port)
      val reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
      userInput = reader.readLine()
      while(!isStopped && userInput != null) {
        println("userInput= "+userInput)
        store(userInput)
        userInput = reader.readLine()
        println("==store data finished==")
      }
      reader.close()
      socket.close()
      logInfo("Stopped receiving")
      restart("Trying to connect again")
    } catch {
      case e: java.net.ConnectException =>
        restart("Error connecting to " + host + ":" + port, e)
      case t: Throwable =>
        restart("Error receiving data", t)
    }
  }
}
```

It passes the compiler and runs smoothly. I did not take the output as i expected, because the hdfs file was empty all the time.

Could anyone give me a hand ?

Comment: yes ，it seems the spark cluster ignored these data from socket. " println("userInput= "+userInput)"  works and it prints the value od userinput correctly . but the next line store(userinput) doesnot work as you  said . what do you mean "that would not work on a background thread" ?

Comment: Someone told me it is bacause i didnot  give enough num-executors(>1) or run under yarn mode  when i spark-submit jar。。。。

Comment: Sorry. My bad.  I was reading the code as if the user had to type data for it to work. I get it now.

Comment: which spark master are you using? you will indeed need 1 executor for your receiver and at least 1 for spark.

Comment: what spark submit command did you issue?

Comment: my command is like the following and i had only one pc in my cluster :           --master local                                                                                                                                   Maybe that is what you said I should use "local[2]" or "yarn "                                  But my rub is since i invoke a new thread to receive data  in my function Onstart(), then why could come out such performence

Comment: i forgot  to let you know that  thanks for your time